# Recursive Join with table

Tags: sql, join, recursion

I have a simple table tblWorkedHours

```
ID int,
PayPeriod int,
MonthEnd date,
WorkedHours float,
ContractHours float,
OwedHours float,
PrvsOwedHours float,
FinalOwedHours float
```

I have two calculated columns called PrvsOwedHours, FinalOwedHours.

```
FinaOWedHours = OWedHOurs+PrvsOwedHours.

PrvsOwedHours is the Previous months FinalOwedHours, that is carried forward into the next month.
```

But what is the best way to do this...should I create a new table every month and join the two or is their some way to do it recursively.

I have no test data im afraid...

Comment: Without test data, you will never be sure the solution works.

Comment: Please specify which RDBMS you are using - if recursion is needed, then the syntax will vary greatly depending on which one.

Comment: Also, try to make an effort before you ask a question. You could set up a fiddle with the tables, to save the time of the people trying to help you. Also, then you can invent some sample data in a sandpit environment. See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6966f2/1

Comment: I have tried with simple data but the join generated an endless loop creating more and more records.  I should explain more...to calculate the FinalOwedHours I need to add in PrvsOwedHours, but this is was last months FinalOwedHours...does any of this make sense? has anyone encountered something like this before and if so how did they solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support window functions and most of these support the cumulative sum.  You can just do the calculation as:

```
select t.*,
       sum(OwedHours) over (order by monthend) - OwedHours as PrevOwedHours,
       sum(OwedHours) over (order by monthend) as FinalOwedHours
from table t;
```